# Should I look for e-mail header fields names in case-sensitive or case-insensitive manner?

Tags: email

Section 2.2 of [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) defined e-mail message header fields. However it doesn't say explicitly if the header name should be interpreted in case-sensitive or case-insensitive manner.

For example, if I want to find the "Carbon Copy" section should I look for "Cc:" in case sensitive manner? Or if a message already has "Cc:" field can it also have "CC:" field? Does the requirement to interpret fields name in case-sensitive or case-insensitive manner apply to all or only select fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the RFC doesn't define it, it is left as an implementation detail.

To be safe, I would go with case-insensitive to allow for different implementations to work without failing.

By the way, RFC 2822 has been obsoleted by [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (which also has no such discussion).

Answer (score 3):

See section 1.2.2. "Syntactic Notation” in RFC 5322. "Characters will be specified either by a decimal value (e.g., the value %d65 for uppercase A and %d97 for lowercase A) or by a case-insensitive literal value enclosed in quotation marks (e.g., "A" for either uppercase or lowercase A).” Later on the header field names are specified in quotes, meaning they are case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you should use case insensitive checks as different clients/servers do different things with the headers.